# How to define the boundary of the 2D region outside of the list of sub-regions?

Tags: list-manipulation, regions, data

Consider the following [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9ulf12r3t5ds5n/data.m?dl=0). It includes a list of tables defining some regions.

```
data = Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "data.m"}], "MX"];
```

This is what it looks like:

```
ListLogLogPlot[Evaluate[data], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Is it possible to evaluate the region's boundary outside the domain covered by the colored curves (plus additionally `10^-3 < x < 75 && 10^-9<x<1`)? It should look like as the domain in black:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Filter data sets 1 and 4 using `HarmonicMeanFilter` (or use your favorite filter) to get rid of the jumps:

```
harmonicMeanFilter = Transpose[
   {#, HarmonicMeanFilter[#2, 50]} & @@ Transpose[#]] &;
```

Plot filtered data sets 1 and 4 together with sets 2 and 5 with the option `Filling -> Top`:

```
lllp1425 = ListLogLogPlot[
   Join[harmonicMeanFilter /@ data[[{1, 4}]], data[[{2, 5}]]], 
   Joined -> True,  Filling -> Top];
```

Extract the polygons and take their union:

```
polygons1425 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion @@ Cases[Normal @ lllp1425, _Polygon, All]];
```

Do the same for data sets 3 and 6:

```
lllp36 = ListLogLogPlot[data[[{3, 6}]], Joined -> True];

polygons36 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   RegionUnion @@ Cases[lllp36, Line[x_] :> Polygon[x], All]];
```

Combine `polygon1425` with `polygon36` and get the boundary region:

```
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion[polygons1425, polygons36];
```

Finally to get the region of interest, take `RegionDifference` between the bounding rectangle of `bdr` and `bdr`:

```
bottomregion = RegionDifference[
  MapAt[{.99 #[[1]], 1.2 #[[2]]} &, BoundingRegion[bdr], {1}], bdr];
```

Show everything together:

```
Show[ListLogLogPlot[data, 
    Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> Range[6], ImageSize -> 700], 
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[bottomregion, BaseStyle -> Yellow]]
```

> picture at the top

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!